Lenovo laptop cpu speed down to 0.5 GHz from 3.0 GHz normal speed when battery connected and plugged in to ac power
This problem of mine has nothing to do with power options.
I really can not understand what is going on.
When the battery is connected and the laptop is plugged in to ac power, laptop cpu speed is so slow. But if I shut down the laptop, remove the battery, plug in the laptop to power and boot up(without the battery of course), the speed is back to normal (3.0 GHz). I have noticed that the battery is not charging when connected to the laptop.
Is this a battery failure? Have you ever seen this problem before?

An abnormal or faulty battery could be overheating the charging circuitry in the laptop. That condition could be being detected by the firmware which in turn could be putting your CPU into a thermal safety (throttling) mode. It is entirely possible that your battery is making your CPU slow. First thing would be to replace the battery, after that you could have a fault in the electronics that charges the battery.

@john Thank you both. I ran the Lenovo Vantage software. It showed that battery charging process was stopped at 1%. It also displayed the message that "charging is stopped due to battery high temperature status" or something like that. So guess, the culprit with the battery that I have to change first. Thank you again.

@Mokubai Thank you. See the the message I posted above.

Lenovo fixed this issue in new versions of BIOS updates. GSCN40WW (May 15,2024)  Fixed in my case
